# Invalid get Index y with Vector2

Tags: math, vector, godot, gdscript, vector2

In Godot, I am making a 2D platformer, but in my player code I get the error:

```
Invalid get index 'y' (on base: 'int')
```

But only when the character touches the ground. My player code is this:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const JUMP_FORCE = 1550
const MOVE_SPEED = 500
const GRAVITY = 60
const MAX_SPEED = 2000

var velocity = Vector2(0,0)
var can_jump = false

func _physics_process(delta):
    var walk = (Input.get_action_strength("right") - Input.get_action_strength("left")) * MOVE_SPEED
    
    velocity.y += GRAVITY
    
    velocity.x += walk
    move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
    velocity.x -= walk
    
    velocity.y = clamp(velocity.y, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
    velocity.x = clamp(velocity.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
    
    var grounded = is_on_floor()
    if grounded:
        can_jump = true
        if velocity.y >= 5:
            velocity = 5
    elif is_on_ceiling() and velocity.y <= -5:
        velocity.y = -5
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
        if grounded:
            velocity.y = -JUMP_FORCE
        elif can_jump:
            can_jump = false
            velocity.y = -JUMP_FORCE
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is a close match to [Invalid set index z with value of type float in gdscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75038196/402022). I would vote to close as duplicate but that question does not have an up-voted answer. Anyway, I will adapt the answer.*

---

Types.

Look, `velocity` is a Variant, initialized to a `Vector2`:

```
var velocity = Vector2(0,0)
```

And - for example - here you use it as a `Vector2`:

```
    velocity.y = clamp(velocity.y, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
    velocity.x = clamp(velocity.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
```

But here `5` is an `int` not a `Vector2`:

```
            velocity = 5
```

So after that `velocity`... Continues to be a Variant, but now it has an `int` value. So when you use it as a `Vector2` it fails. Because an `int` does not have `x`, `y`.

---

You can declare `velocity` to be a `Vector2` explicitly:

```
var velocity:Vector2 = Vector2()
```

Or implicitly (inferred from the value you assigned):

```
var velocity:= Vector2()
```

And then Godot will tell you that this line:

```
            velocity = 5
```

Is an error, because you are trying to set an `int` to a `Vector2`.

---

You could either want to set only one component to `5`, for example:

```
            velocity.y = 5
```

Or you want to set the length of the vector to `5`, which you could do like this:

```
            velocity = velocity.normalized() * 5
```

Or you want to set both components to `5`, which can be this:

```
            velocity.x = 5
            velocity.y = 5
```

Or this:

```
            velocity = Vector2(5, 5)
```

Write the code that you mean.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to say which line was the problem but it looked like you figured it it, so thanks. This helps a lot. It was a typo that I somehow didn't see. I hade put velocity = 5 on accident instead of velocity.y = 5.